# strapi graphql Cannot query anything

Tags: strapi

Reading article [A Deep Dive into Strapi GraphQL](https://strapi.io/blog/a-deep-dive-into-strapi-graph-ql)

REST API work fine

```
http://localhost:1337/api/blogs?filters[id][$eq]=1
```

But GraphQL Not

```
query {
    blogs {
        id
        Title
        Body
    }
}
```

Response

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Cannot query field \"id\" on type \"BlogEntityResponseCollection\".",
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Strapi v4.0.7 node v14.17.5
Using GraphQL extension for chrome and Altai client for query
Try start Strapi with:

- yarn start
- yarn develop

Comment: change to for work
    query{
      blogs{
        data{
          id
        }
      }
    }

Answer (score 0):

using GraphQL playground for chrome hints i make queries like that, different from article

```
query {
  blog(id: 1) {
    data {
      attributes{
        Title
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

querying all the blogs

```
query {
  blogs  {
    data {
      attributes{
        Title
        Body
      }
    }
  }
}
```

querying single blog

```
query {
  blog (id: 1)  {
    data {
      attributes{
        Title
        Body
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This solution worked for me

Strapi changes Goto - settings-> Roles-> Public-> Permissions section

In this section you need to enable your collection methods, e.g.- find, update, delete